Why is centerdot distributivity broken
Does anyone else have this problem?
CenterDot[CenterDot[a, b] - CenterDot[b, a], d]

returns
-d b.a + (a.b).d

It's not distributive!!! There's only one dot in the first term.
I tried to set the behaviour
CenterDot[a_ - b_, c_] := CenterDot[a, c] - CenterDot[b, c]

But the lack of distributivity persists
I am using version 14. I use the package Pauli Algebra. I custom install it by pasting all the directories into the addons folder because the install.m file doesnt work. There are some lines there that tweak the behaviour of centerdot:
(* ----- Dot Product ----- *)
(* [ Definition ] *)
(* Definition of dot product. *)
CenterDot::xdim="The matrices `1` are incompatable in 
dimensions.";
CenterDot[A_\[Sigma]]:=A;
CenterDot[___,0,___]:=0;

me:CenterDot[As:_\ 
[Sigma]..]:=Check[Times@@Flatten@Reap[IndexProduct@@@Thread[{As},\ 
[Sigma]]],Message[CenterDot::xdim, 
{As}];HoldForm[me],Thread::tdlen];

(* [ Algebraic Properties ] *)
(* Pull out factors *)
CenterDot[A___,B_Times,C___]:=Times@@Lookup[#,False,{}] 
CenterDot[A,Times@@Lookup[#,True,{}],C]&@GroupBy[List@@B,\ 
[Sigma]PolynomialQ];
(* Distribute over plus *)
me:CenterDot[___,_Plus,___]:=Distribute[Unevaluated[me],Plus];

After importing the paulialgebra package, the behaviour of centerdot is (a-b).c = -b 1.c + a.c
I also add my own lines because somehow b.1=b is not default behaviour. So I added:
CenterDot[1, x_] := x;
CenterDot[x_, 1] := x;

And that's when the behaviour changes to (a-b).c = -b c + a.c

I don't get the same result as you. Can you please try it on a fresh kernel? And tell us which version you are using.

I get (a\[CenterDot]b - b\[CenterDot]a)\[CenterDot]d, just like @Domen.

I added answers
